# Bayer filter mosaic

Tags: camera, sensor

[image]

Hello,

- How a yellow or any other color that is not **rgb** light, get throw the Bayer filter since only allows the **RGB** value to pass ?

Comment: short answer: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/Yellow_Color.htm  longer answer: yellow is a lot of red+green and little blue

Comment: i know but lets say ,,  a yellow color is reflected from a object as specific wavelength and that wave hits the a blue pixel in the filter only a blue, it wont let it pass and is this the case or i understand it all wrong ?

Comment: neither real-life objects nor the filter-pixels are monochromatic (i.e. using a single-wavelength). Theres always a spectrum involved and the output is then related to the "overlap" of those

Comment: i don't get it ,,,  could you explane the filtering process in detailed way ,,, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You get some transmission of yellow through all three filters](http://micro.magnet.fsu.edu/primer/digitalimaging/images/cmos/cmoschipsfigure4.jpg)
.

Comment: Yes , i found that the yellow is green and red not in signal wavelength but is actually tow wave length ...